# How to disable bluetooth in Android API 33

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#disable()

```
public boolean disable ()
```

This method was deprecated in API level 33.
Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU, applications are not allowed to enable/disable Bluetooth. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU or above, this API will always fail and return false. If apps are targeting an older SDK (Build.VERSION_CODES.S or below), they can continue to use this API.

**How to implement properly disabling bluetooth?**

I have no problem with enable bluetooth, I do like this (following https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/setup):

```
if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
  val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
  startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
}
```

I was searching for solution, but in Android documentation they did not add proper implementation for disabling BT in Android API 33.

Answer (score -2):

There is a simple reason why a normal application cannot simply turn off the Bluetooth sub-system in Android.

Nowadays, the Bluetooth sub-system is used by a large number of applications running simultaneously. One example is the [Exposure Notifications Framework](https://developers.google.com/android/exposure-notifications/exposure-notifications-api) introduced for COVID 19 which is even part of the operating system. So if individual applications could simply switch off this sub-system, a large number of other applications would be negatively affected.

If you still feel that it is imperative for your application that Bluetooth be turned off, then ask the user to do so via the System menu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Can we call a request to disable Bluetooth through the system settings (without stopping app) just like a request to enable Bluetooth?

Comment: Which statement in my answer gave you the impression that your application could somehow disable the Bluetooth sub-system? The most important word in my first sentence is indeed 'cannot' ;-)

Comment: Android should let the user choose with a "dangerous" permission if an app can do that or not. Some users want to use automated apps to automatically turn off bluetoothot or wifi during the night while they have their devices next to the head when sleeping (this is just an example).

Comment: I think your comment is off-topic. Please explain this to the Google systems engineers who make these decisions. Don't shoot the messenger.